# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Delete::delete()

Tags: methods, undefined, call

please can someone advice on making this code compatible, possibly it got broken during PHP 7.4 upgrade... it's a solution developed 5 years ago and now it got broken.

I'm not developer...so apologies for that possibly trivial request.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Delete::delete()

```
$userRightModel = new UserRightDb();
$userRightSelectModel = $userRightModel->getSelectModel();
$userRightSelectModel->setWhereEqual(UserRightDb::COLUMN_USER_ID, $id);
$userRightList = $userRightSelectModel->get();
foreach($userRightList as $userRightObject) {
  $userRightModel = new UserRightDb();
  $userRightDeleteModel = $userRightModel->getDeleteModel();
  $userRightDeleteModel->setValue($userRightObject);
  $userRightDeleteModel->delete();  <--- here it's broken
}
```

Possibly delete() is called from Delete.php which is included into DB.php library...

```
<?php
  include_once 'MySql.php';

  class Delete extends MySql {

    protected $_table   = null;
    protected $_columns = array();
    protected $_values  = array();
    protected $_object_name = null;

    public function __construct() {
      foreach($this->_values as $object) {
        $queryString = $this->toString($object);
        $mysql_data = $this->execute($queryString);
      }
    }

    public function setObjectName($objectName) {
      $this->_object_name = $objectName;
    }

    public function setTable($tableName) {
      $this->_table = $tableName;
    }

    public function setColumns($columns) {
      $this->_columns = $columns;
    }

    public function setValue($value) {
      $this->_values = array();
      $this->_values[] = $value;
    }

    protected function toString($object) {

      $result = 'DELETE FROM {table} WHERE {where}';

      $result = str_replace('{table}', '`' . $this->_table . '`', $result);

      $where = Db::COLUMN_ID . MySQL::EQUAL . "'" . $object->getId() ."'";
      $result = str_replace('{where}', $where, $result);

      return $result;
    }

  }

?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: No suggestions even to try from experts ? :-(

Comment: Please really nobody knows ?